# xampp setting document root

Tags: apache, xampp, root

Im having issues with trying to set the document root on xampp

I have made the following changes in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/bk"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/bk">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I try to go to my localhost in chrome I get an `oops google chrome could not...` message, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: restarted the server after making changes? :just making sure:

Comment: yes a few times, even restarted the computer

Comment: @poepje it turns out the problem for me was that the IP google was returning was different from the one in my access logs, if your using linux go in to SSH and use the `who` command to see the IP your logged in with

Comment: What do you mean, Google? I'm using xampp for apache/localhost, don't you?

Comment: @poepje I should have been more clear, I searched for my ip address on google from sites like ipchicken.com.

Comment: Ok thanks! However I still don't understand how an IP-address has any affection on something you do offline (localhost)..